# React Context is not passing 1/2 fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

So I'm learning how to use React context, I have found this example which is very helpful: https://codesandbox.io/s/login-flow-w-react-context-api-p9j96?file=/src/Login/index.js

Since `useSetState` can no longer be used, I tried to import `useState` from `react`, but it doesn't work the same, `useState` only passing password to the login function, as can be seen here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/login-flow-w-react-context-api-forked-njs1kt?file=/src/Login/index.js

Console also threw this error:

> A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

Anyway I can fix this? Thank you guys so much, and happy holiday!!

Answer (score 0):

I belive I have solved your problem. You can checkout link below

https://codesandbox.io/s/login-flow-w-react-context-api-forked-l3x24v?file=/src/Login/index.js

If you have object or array in state you should update like this:

```
setState((prevState)=>{return {...prevState,property:value}})
```

Also I suggest you to update your react ot 17 or above.

There was another issue about called "Event Pooling"

https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-event-pooling.html

That is why I used `e.persist();`

Comment: Thank you, it works for me. Because the example is react 16 so I keep it there, but the problem is the same. Have a good day sir.